# CSS left to right, reappear left animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, overflow

I have an image that I animated with CSS. It goes from -200px left to 2100px right and then starts over. What I want to do is when part of the image is disappearing to the right, I want that part to show on the left side and continue the animation.

Here is an example of what I want, you can see how part of the text that goes off-screen to the right reappears left and continues the animation. I want to do the same thing with CSS or JS.

[image: Example Gif]

Part of my code right now (I made it small - don't view full screen):

```css
body {
background-color: pink;
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(310%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please show us some code!

Comment: @jefi I edited the post a little bit, the code snippet is a smaller version of my code (normally my "box" is going from "- box width" left to "100% body width + box width" right. I believe the gif clearly shows what I want to achieve.